# Clipboard functionality in email template

Tags: html, node.js, email, email-attachments

I want to send a coupon code in the email template. 
A Small button that will copy the content of a input element on the clipboard.

By email Template, i mean i want to send a email which will have a coupon code and there will be a button in the email template which will allow me to copy it to clipboard. Can this be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Considering that javascript cannot be added inline to the email template, i couldnt think of any other solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer is No - This feature would require Javascript.

Long answer - Yes (in a different way) - You could use unique query strings on the button URL (eg `?USER=1&COUPON_CODE=123`) that way you could automatically carry the unique coupon code from the email to the landing page form field.

To do this you could assign each member in your database a unique coupon within the CSV file (or whatever you use) and set up a merge field within your ESP and use that to automatically create the strings. For example, your string would look like this when you code it `href="http://www.yousite.com/?[%coupon%]"` and your ESP will do the rest providing the database is set up correctly.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This could be misleading, there is no "workaround" for clipboard use in email templates, all major email clients block javascript and the clipboard functionality requires javascript. So short and long answer is no, you cant' have a button that can copy to the clipboard in the email template.

Answer (score 7):

Since clipboard's content is changed with javascript, there is no way to do that in an email.

You could, however, build an URL with the coupon code as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did the solution with my email service provider (`ConvertKit`). They have a handy functionality where you can pull subscriber custom fields into the email like `{{ subscriber.coupon_code }}`, and you can use those in a URL that will pre-fill, say, a social post. I actually use their `ClickUp` CRM record "task" ID for their code and their referral link URL slug. I use Make.com automation to pull the `ClickUp` ID into their `ConvertKit` record as a custom field, then the method above to pull that into the social share buttons in my email. Of course I also need to create their referral links, which I also do through Make.com, creating a Rebrandly UTM-tagged shortlink for every customer (this gives me an extra place to cross-reference the clicks each link gets, plus if the user prefers to type out their link they can do that too).

Answer (score 0):

I made it but only in salesforce marketing cloud and used a cloudpage whete I could apply JS
See my whole post here:
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/rolandeder28674516a_sfmc-salesforcemarketingcloud-salesforce-activity-7082344519857246209-L9S_?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_android

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34646874)