# Is there a way to copy some text from email to clipboard?

Tags: html-email, clipboard

I am a photographer and I have a personalised email that I send to the clients when I deliver the photos. In that email there are the gallery links, and also a password to access them.
I would like, if I could find a way, to copy that password in the clipboard.

I was thinking maybe put a link on my website, set the password as an URL parameter, then intercept it in a new page, copy in clipboard and close that page, if possible.

How does that sound to you and how can I do it? :D

Comment: Unfortunately there are no copy to clipboard features that will work in emails. For that functionality you will need eternal scripts. Building on what you mentioned above, you could have the password encoded in the email behind a link. Once it reaches you site and if that variable exists in the URL, get the value, decode and add it in. (just a thought)

Comment: As Syfer says, that should be possible. I would suggest looking up each individual thing - there's lots of answers for each (extracting from URL parameter; copying to clipboard, closing page).

Comment: The Answer to this question has already been answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638467/clipboard-functionality-in-email-template

Comment: Musahib Khan - unfortunately, it doesn't apply to my situation :)